# issue with checking all element type of an Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typeof

I am trying to check all the element type of an array in javascript. I am actually writing a function which whould only accept an array with numbers.

so

```
[1,2,-3,-4,0]  //valid input
[1,2,-3b,-4a,0]  //Invalid input
```

I am trying to achieve the following by using every() function of javascript as follows,

```
try {
                    if (!inputArr.every(x => typeof x === 'number')) {
                           throw 'input array should only have numbers';
                    }
                }
                catch (err) {
                    return err;
                }
```

but getting error. when I investigate it further than realized that,

```
typeof 1 // number
typeof 1a // error
```

so there is no way we can check the type of a alphanumeric value.  can someone please suggest some options here. I am using pure javascript ES5 Or ES6.

Comment: you can also use [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Comment: @Manatax But `isNaN("123")` would return `false`, even though `"123"` is not a number. If that suits OP's needs, then it would work. If the goal is a stricter check, then `typeof` seems like the way to go.

Comment: @Manatax, I need to check strictly that supplied input array has all the numbers ONLY. isNan will not work here as mentioned by @ Michael Geary

Comment: Since `[1,2,-3b,-4a,0]` is invalid syntax, and your program would not even run, should we assume that the input is a kind-of array represented as a string, as in `"[1,2,-3b,-4a,0]"`?

Comment: @ torazaburo, no, actually it is a generic  javascript function which takes an array ( all element must be numbers) and process the array and return some output. Now I want to make sure that passed array has all number. a tester caught this secanrio by passing an input as [1,2,-3b,-4a,0]. Now I am kind of stuck.

Comment: @ torazaburo, actually, you are kind of right. we can change the function signature by accepting an string instead of an array but than , first I need to make sure that passed string is an array and than will check the element type of the array.

Comment: @ torazaburo, would you suggest a way to check whether a supplied string is an array or not.  I tried 
 `Array.isArray("[1,2,-3,-4,0]");     //false
"[1,2,-3,-4,0]"  instanceof Array //false`

Comment: @Akash Wait, are you saying the input to your function is a _string_, not an _array_, and the string may be something like `"[1,2,-3a,4]"`? That is a whole different question. I would first use `JSON.parse()` to attempt to convert this string to a JavaScript array. If it throws an exception, then you had something like the "-3a" in it and should reject. Otherwise, run your test loop on the resulting array.

Comment: @ Michael Geary : Actually, the current use case was to provide an array as an input ( not as a string) but later-on based on some suggestions, if I can achieve what I am trying to by passing an input array as string than I can change that use case.  So Now I am first pasring the input as JSON.parse() and than checking the parsed output for an array by using Array.isArray() function. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[1,2,-3b,-4a,0]` is invalid syntax, and your program would not even run. Therefore, we will assume that the input is a string, as in `"[1,2,-3b,-4a,0]"`. In that case:

```
function check(input) {
  try {
    const array = JSON.parse(input);
    return array.every(x => typeof x === 'number');
  } catch(e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```